# Drupal database connection

Tags: database

Is it necessary to connect to drupal database in order to fetch something from database? OR no if I have drupal installed so no need to make connection in any template file in order to fetch data?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Have you seen [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) project?

Answer (score 0):

The database connection is handled elsewhere, you do not need to write a new connection function in your template file.

You can use this:
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is yes...Drupal uses a entity value attribute (EVA) data model which makes pulling tabular data directly from a MySQL client challenging at best.

You would be better off installing the feeds or Views data export module(s) to retreive the data you want and export as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

| I have drupal installed so no need to make connection in any template file in order to fetch data?

You should not be fetching data in template files, I highly recommend you instead create a small custom module and use either a theme_hook or  preprocess functions to push data in your templates. You really want to avoid having "logic" in templates.

You can query the DB with [db_query](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) or any other [Database api function](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) in your custom module's code.